# English words to a vector of numbers using Python

Tags: python, csv, numbers, cpu-word

I have a database in CSV format comprising the identity (first name, last name, gender, phone number, zip code) of a several hundred persons.  I intend to hide the first and last names to preserve identity.  Is there a way in Python to input a word and convert it to a vector of numbers? Or, should this be done using machine learning techniques? I have basic knowledge of Python.

A snippet of the database is attached herewith.

[image]

Comment: You can create a mapping for them!
If you can show a sample of your data, I'll help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send your input text to a hash function:

```
import hashlib

with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    lines = csv_file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        hash_object = hashlib.sha256(line.encode())
        print(int(hash_object.hexdigest(), 16))
```

Comment: Thanks!  How do I loop it over all the entries (including first name and last name).  As I have mentioned, my Python skill is preliminary.  This is a small part of my work, so I do not intend to spend much time learning programming.  Also, is there a way to get a smaller string of numbers?

Comment: you mentioned that your input is a CSV file. so simply take each line you read from the file and send it to the hash function. as for the output length, you can pick as many digit as you want from the suffix. suppose that you have a long string in the variable "output" and you want the last 8 digits, then use output[-8:] . one warning though: make sure you take enough digits to guarantee that your ID is a unique number (assuming that you're looking for uniqueness).

Comment: @Nanda  "I do not intend to spend much time learning programming." Unless you can hire someone else, you have to learn programming anyway...

Comment: For the purpose of converting the names to pseudonyms, this is a terrible way because md5 is reversible and there can only be so many names. It's even worse if the algorithm/salt is known.

Comment: true, md5 is not a good choice, but the hashlib module comes with plenty of other algorithms which can not be reversed.

Comment: I am having trouble reading each row of the CSV file and sending it to the hash function.  How can this be resolved?

Comment: @Nanda I edited the answer to include reading the csv file. also changed the hashing algorithm to sha256, which is more secured.